# Scroll iframe to anchor without id field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am loadin an iframe on the page, i only want to show part of it, the problem is, the place i want to show in the iframe doesn't contain an id field, so the below code doesn't work.

```
<iframe src"thedoamin.com #anchor" />
```

I tried to add an id field to the part i want to show in the source domain, but the part itself is a plugin that loads with some other javascript. So the above iframe doesn't scroll to the id anchor at all.

I think the problem is that the iframe loads first in my page, and it couldn't find the id field in the iframe because the part hasn't been loaded yet, so it doesn't do anything. It feels like i am stuck in an infinite loop.

**How can i show only part of the iframe without an id field????**

I also tried using .load() function, but the part i want to show is not just html, it depends on other javascript and css too, so it doesn't show properly.

Comment: Please share the code you tried before

Comment: Also your link should be on the format `http://thedomain.com/#anchor` - or `page.html#anchor` - If the iframe content is from the same origin, you might be able to extract what you need with jQuery after rendering

Comment: @mplungjan I tried them already, it doesn't work, i tried with other ids on the page, and it works not matter if its /# or html# or html #, so i don't think thats the problem

Comment: You can take a div with some `max-width` or `max-height` with `overflow:hidden` and then position your iframe inside that div with `margin-top` or `margin-left` to whatever position you want to show.

Comment: @Arun Thats everything there is to try....except if you want the .load function. $("#test").load(”thedomain.com #anchor");

Comment: @Sidharth overflow:hidden and margin-top with height fixed it, thanks

Comment: @EricWang you can vote my answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my updated answer for as i commented :

You can try taking a your iframe within a div and then set your iframe's position according to that div.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 736px;">
  <iframe scrolling="no" src="your_page" style="margin-left:-185px; height:859px; margin-top:-533px; width:926px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```